# Any way to resume killed tmux server?

Tags: tmux

I had to kill a tmux process with lots of sessions as tmux wasnt responding. I would have to do quite a bit of manual work in order to start the sessions again. Is there any way to resume the server and get back the sessions to save time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tmux-resurrect plugin in the future to save your tmux session. https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect

To add more detail straight up copied from the README to satisfy the stackexchange bot:

This plugin goes to great lengths to save and restore all the details from your tmux environment. Here's what's been taken care of:

- all sessions, windows, panes and their order
  current working directory for each pane
  exact pane layouts within windows (even when zoomed)
- active and alternative session
- active and alternative window for each session
- windows with focus
- active pane for each window
- "grouped sessions" (useful feature when using tmux with multiple monitors)
- programs running within a pane

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).